# powershell print page of web client in pdf

Tags: powershell, pdf, printing, webclient

I am trying to print the web page from a web client into a pdf file.

I first call the page url in a web client object:

```
$ie = New-Object -COMObject InternetExplorer.Application

$ie.visible = $true

$ie.Navigate('http://www.stackoverflow.com')

While ($ie.Busy) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 400 }

'Done!'
```

and when it's loaded, just call the ExecWB with parameters 6,2 like found in this forum:

```
$ie.ExecWB(6,2)

while ( $ie.busy ) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 400 }

'Done 2!'

<#$ie.quit()#>
```

I am working with PowerShell 5 under Windows 10.

I have following the first issue: the parameter 2 does not work. I will always prompted.

I don't know how to specify the name of the pdf file I want to print in.

I found nothing in the documentation.

ExecWB does not seem to be a feature in PowerShell 5 any more.

Second issue: if I put ie.quit() then nothing happens. The page will not be print.

Any ideas?

Thanx

Jerome

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org) to do what you want. You can install it via chocolatey: `cinst whktmltopdf`. It works with remote or local html files.

Comment: I had a look at the documentation: I think I could call the program whktmltopdf.exe from PowerShell but I could not parameter anything from there. Am I wrong? I have another issue to get the HTML source of the URI: DownloadString seems not  to be a feature in PowerShell 5 anymore...Very strange !

Comment: What parameters do you need ?

Comment: whktmltopdf has that (`-O landscape`) and its already searchable.